# Intermittent Highcharts heatmap issue when using EO.PDF

Tags: jquery, pdf, highcharts, heatmap

I've got a very strange issue when using EO.PDF (http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/UrlToPdf.aspx, we are using the C# 16.0.36.0 version, but the latest has been tested and makes no difference) to make a PDF report of some highcharts heatmaps.
The issue only occurs intermittently and only seems to affect the YAxis for values 8&9.

See **Hourly** example;
[image]
We can see here that the hours of 8 & 9 are inexplicably missing.

The issue also occurs at **Daily** resolution;
[image]
Where the 8th and 9th days of the month are missing.

However, the issue does not seem to occur at **Weekly** resolution;
[image]

Despite my best efforts I am unable to find out why **weekly** works and the others do not.
I have tried creating a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8ejyxmrv/8/) which I have embedded in the same report which was PDF'd and that was fine.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  type: 'heatmap'
},
title: {
  text: null
},
subtitle: {
  text: null
},
exporting: {
  enabled: false
},
xAxis: {

  type: 'datetime',
  showLastLabel: true,
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: false,
  tickLength: 16,
  tickPosition:'inside'
},
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  allowDecimals: false,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  tickWidth: 1,
  reversed: true
},
legend: {
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0
},
colorAxis: {
  stops: [
    [0, '#3060cf'],
    [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
    [0.9, '#c4463a'],
    [1, '#c4463a']
  ],
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  labels: {
    format: '{value}℃'
  }
},
series: [{
  nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
  colsize: 24 * 366 * 36e5, // one day
  data: [{
    "x": 1293840000000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 12.369916666666667
  }, {
    "x": 1293840000000,
    "y": 10,
    "value": 10.6350390625
  }, {
    "x": 1293840000000,
    "y": 11,
    "value": 8.553833333333333
  }, {
    "x": 1293840000000,
    "y": 12,
    "value": 5.47380376344086
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 1,
    "value": 4.351263440860215
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 2,
    "value": 4.1775
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 3,
    "value": 7.175680555555555
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 4,
    "value": 5.4682361111111115111115
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 5,
    "value": 9.231048387096774
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 6,
    "value": 11.234402777777778
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 7,
    "value": 13.0563037634408686,
    "TargetVariance": null
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 8,
    "value": 13.888951612903226
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 11.062791666666667
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 10,
    "value": 8.0660546875
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 11,
    "value": 5.921791666666667
  }, {
    "x": 1325376000000,
    "y": 12,
    "value": 4.618225806451613
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 1,
    "value": 3.0773790322580643
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 2,
    "value": 2.013720238095238
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 3,
    "value": 1.3879305555555554
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 4,
    "value": 4.8272916666666665
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 5,
    "value": 7.882486559139785
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 6,
    "value": 11.147875
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 7,
    "value": 14.683279569892473
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 8,
    "value": 14.095846774193548
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 11.734722222222222
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 10,
    "value": 10.861888020833334
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 11,
    "value": 6.297958333333334
  }, {
    "x": 1356998400000,
    "y": 12,
    "value": 5.835255376344086
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 1,
    "value": 4.799771505376344
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 2,
    "value": 4.816517857142857
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 3,
    "value": 6.157361111111111
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 4,
    "value": 8.558361111111111
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 5,
    "value": 10.086021505376344
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 6,
    "value": 12.808152777777778
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 7,
    "value": 14.819233870967741
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 8,
    "value": 12.497110215053764
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 13.144097222222221
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 10,
    "value": 10.852981770833333
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 11,
    "value": 7.6481111111111115
  }, {
    "x": 1388534400000,
    "y": 12,
    "value": 5.427016129032258
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 1,
    "value": 3.3871774193548387
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 2,
    "value": 3.3910565476190477
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 3,
    "value": 4.690097222222223
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 4,
    "value": 7.053194444444444
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 5,
    "value": 8.070067204301075
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 6,
    "value": 11.259694444444444
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 7,
    "value": 12.499126344086022
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 8,
    "value": 12.689126344086022
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 9.845888888888888
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 10,
    "value": 8.764348958333333
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 11,
    "value": 7.338375
  }, {
    "x": 1420070400000,
    "y": 12,
    "value": 6.968682795698925
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 1,
    "value": 4.054005376344086
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 2,
    "value": 2.8649568965517243
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 3,
    "value": 3.9838055555555556
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 4,
    "value": 5.634944444444445
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 5,
    "value": 10.787782258064516
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 6,
    "value": 13.709222222222222
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 7,
    "value": 14.24284946236559
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 8,
    "value": 14.085618279569893
  }, {
    "x": 1451606400000,
    "y": 9,
    "value": 14.304195804195805
  }],
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
  },
  turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
}]

});
```

**JSFiddle iFrame embedded in report and PDFd** - 8th and 9th Months present
[image]

**Same heatmap as part of report** - 8th and 9th Months Missing
[image]

---

I have tried removing pretty much any chart customisation code except the data including all highcharts modules except Highstock (v4.2.4) and Heatmaps add-on (v4.2.6) and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Its also important to note that the issue does not occur when viewed in any browser (IE9,10,11, Firefox & Chrome tested) and only occurs when in the PDF.

So, my question is, has anyone seen this or a similar issue who can help or point me towards a solution as I am officially stumped on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you consider using Highcharts exporting? It will give you a possibility to export your chart to pdf.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński That would be fine if we were doing individual chart exports, but the export is part of a larger report which will have several charts and other stats. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, updating to the latest version of Essential Objects' PDF, e.g. version 17.1.65, fixes this issue.